# Disabled select list with Html.DropDownListFor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm creating a select list by using the Html.DropDownListFor() helper in asp.net mvc. Does this helper class allow to disable this select list by default upon creation? e.g. output should look like:
   `<select` **disabled**`>`
    `<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>`
   `</select>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create a disabled drop down list you could try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Value,
    Model.Items,
    new { disabled = "disabled" }
)
```

Comment: How would you do this in jquery or javascript?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i have similar problem could you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650267/when-dropdownlitfor-is-disabled-value-always-passd-as-0