# When dropdownlitFor is disabled , value always passed as 0

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

This is my `dropdownlistFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.objTicket.DepartmentId, new SelectList(Model.objTicket.Departments, "DepartmentId", "Department"), 
"-- Select Department--", new { id = "Deptment"}, disabled="disabled")
```

How can I pass the value which is already stored in `objTicket.DepartmentId` ?

If i change remove disabled ="disabled", i get my correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form fields are submitted using Names instead of Ids. Disabled controls values wont be submitted by browsers. Place a `@Html.HiddenFor` field with same name and different Ids as given below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.objTicket.DepartmentId, new SelectList(Model.objTicket.Departments, "DepartmentId", "Department"),Department--", new { id = "Deptment"}, disabled="disabled")
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.objTicket.DepartmentId, new { id="Deptment2" })
```